# Calculate accuracy over the entire training set

Tags: tensorflow

I am running a first test of a convolutional neural network with tensor flow. I adapted the recommended method with queue runners from the programming guide (see session definition below). Output is the last result from the cnn (here is only this last step given). label_batch_vector is the training label batch.

```
output = tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1
label_batch_vector = tf.one_hot(label_batch, 33)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(output, 1), tf.argmax(label_batch_vector, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())

print_accuracy = tf.Print(accuracy, [accuracy])

# Create a session for running operations in the Graph.
sess = tf.Session()

# Initialize the variables (like the epoch counter).
sess.run(init_op)

# Start input enqueue threads.
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

try:
    while not coord.should_stop():
        # Run training steps or whatever
        sess.run(train_step)
        sess.run(print_accuracy)

except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print('Done training -- epoch limit reached')
finally:
    # When done, ask the threads to stop.
    coord.request_stop()

# Wait for threads to finish.
coord.join(threads)
sess.close()
```

My problem is that accuracy is calculated for each batch and I would like it calculated for each epoch. I would need to do the following: initialize a epoch_accuracy tensor, for each of the calculated batch accuracies in the epoch add it to the epoch_accuracy. At the end of the epoch show the calculated training set accuracy. However I am not finding any such example with the this queue threads that I implemented (which is actually the recommended method from TensorFlow). Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To compute accuracy on the stream of data (your sequence of batches, here), you can use the `tf.metrics.accuracy` function in tensorflow. See its doc [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/accuracy)

You define the op like this

```
_, accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(y_true, y_pred)
```

Then you can update the accuracy in this way:

```
sess.run(accuracy)
```

PS: all functions in `tf.metrics` (auc, recall, etc.) support streaming

Comment: I have not tested yet, but I have the feeling it will compute a single value for all the epochs. I need a value for each epoch.

Comment: I have now tested and given the way in which I produce the inputs it will not be so easy to compute per epoch.

Comment: I have a question: the weights in the network model are being updated continuously after each batch following sess.run(train_step). Then what is computed as accuracy is not the accuracy with the latest weights over the whole dataset, but the accuracy as a mean of the computed accuracy with changing weights until the current time ? Did I understand correctly ?

Comment: I managed to implement a final solution. The conclusion is that with streaming is not possible to test accuracy and optimized the weights in the same session. I saved the model after the training and from a different script I started the queues, loaded the model and then tested the accuracy only. I am marking the answer as correct because, as suggested, I used tf.metrics.accuracy to calculated the accuracy.